# php works on wamp but not on 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that works perfectly with WAMP server, but when Im trying the 000webhost server I get errors.
i.e. error on line 11 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document.
however under the error I get the right answer to the query, but not in the format I asked for.
can anyone help?
here is the code:

```
<?php   
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("ataxi");
$src= $_GET['src'];
$dest = $_GET['dest'];
$day= $_GET['day'];
$hour = $_GET['hour'];
$luggage= $_GET['luggage']; 
$query="SELECT price, estime FROM prices WHERE src='$src' and dest='$dest' and day='$day' and hour='$hour' and luggage=$luggage;"; 
$result= mysql_query($query) or die("error:".$query);
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"',true);
echo "<table>\n"; 
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<record>\n";
    echo "<price>".$row['price']."</price>\n";
    echo "<estime>".$row['estime']."</estime>\n";
    echo "</record>\n";
    }
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING** Your code is very suseptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Lol 000webhost. That is all. Try seeing whether there is extra whitespace after the closing `?>` tag, or before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: What is the format you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: I want to get the result as:

'<table>
<record>
<price>70</price>
<estime>20</estime>
</record>
</table>'

instead Im getting:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 11 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

70 20

Comment: what is the encoding of the file ?

Comment: Why are you generating XML by concatenating strings? Why are you interpolating variables into SQL without escaping them?!

Comment: Remove the header line so you can see the raw response body. With the application/xml content type you won't be able to see any PHP errors

Comment: I also tried text/xml. I didnt get the error but I also didnt get the right format

Comment: Can you add the response body to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

000webhost appends analytics code by default. It *could* be wreaking havoc on your XML.

You can disable it by going to:
http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php.

Comment: Unbelievable. If you had just looked at the response body, this would have been **obvious**

Comment: 000webhost is a decent free host, but you have to weed through their forum to find that link. I'd like to add that you should look into protecting your code from SQL injection attacks. @David is correct. "View source" is part of every browser. Firefox's Firebug and Web Developer add-ons are even better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First: I doubt 000webhost are giving you root access?

Second: You can't submit header requests after already outputting to the screen, put the header line at the top of your script.

Comment: the header is in a right position , no printing before and this is probably how he ran the script on the wamp server (local one)

Comment: No it isn't, if the "or die" echos out an error, then he tries to send a header it will fail. So he doesn't have permission, the query fails, which echos the error, then trying to change the header will result in the error he is getting

Comment: @AbePetrillo die ends the script execution

Comment: that's right because the mysql_connect is wrong , but if it's right and the query is right no echo until the header

Comment: @DavidCaunt Good Point, I forgot about that

Comment: @elibyy We're basically an interactive debugger for kande and his bad, bad code

Comment: I tried to put it at the top but it didnt work. of course that I changed the  name of the host, username and password.
I can see that I get the data, but not in the right format. Also when trying through eclipse I get an error